# How to calculate total number of a row from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

I've a row named 'quantity' and I've numbers of quantity in this field.How can I calculate the total numbers of quantity in codeigniter and pass them to view ?
I have fetch the 'quantity' row from database table and calculate them in for loop.

Comment: I assume you mean column rather than row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`select_sum`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#class-reference) query builder method.

```
$total_quantity = 0;

$row = $this->db->select_sum('quantity', 'total_quantity')->get('your_table')->row();

if (isset($row)) {
    $total_quantity = $row->total_quantity;
}

$this->load->view('your_view', ['total_quantity' => $total_quantity]);
```